# Adding RadioGroup in Tab

Tags: extjs4.2

I' have added Radiogroup inside the docked Tree panel.

items 
1. Global Search - default this is selected
2. User Items

Here i'm loading the radio button inside the Tab Panel

When loading the first tab "Global Search" is selected. When opened the second tab and checked the "User Items", now the first tab "Global Search" is unchecked

How do i independently load the radioGroup for the different tabs, when i click on the tab 2, why the tab1 radio is getting unchecked, they should behave independently

```
{
                xtype: 'radiogroup',
                columns: 1,
                    width : 200,
                    vertical: true,
                    items: [
                        {boxLabel: 'Global Search', itemId:'gSearch', name: 'elnSwitchAllTree', inputValue: 'Global Search', checked: true},
                        {boxLabel: 'User Preferences', itemId:'uSearchPref',name: 'elnSwitchAllTree', inputValue: 'User Preferences'} 
                    ]}
```

Answer (score 0):

In radio group you are given the names are similar for all the tabs 
Give different names for different tabs then it will work.

```
Tab1:
 {boxLabel: 'Global Search', itemId:'gSearch', name: 'elnSwitchAllTree', inputValue: 'Global Search', checked: true},
 {boxLabel: 'User Preferences', itemId:'uSearchPref',name: 'elnSwitchAllTree', inputValue: 'User Preferences'} 

Tab2 : 
{boxLabel: 'Global Search', itemId:'gSearch', name: 'elnSwitchAllTreeTAB2', inputValue: 'Global Search', checked: true},
{boxLabel: 'User Preferences', itemId:'uSearchPref',name: 'elnSwitchAllTreeTAB2', inputValue: 'User Preferences'}
```

like that you have to have different names for different tabs then it will work try this

Comment: I also got the same problem once i changed the names of the radio groups then it started working if you want i will add my code